# Accessing the data passed using @Input decorator

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have a child component that looks like this

**Child Component**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child-component',
   //TemplateUrl, Styles and Providers
})

export Class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input()
  arrayToGet; //An array that I want to pass from Parent to child

  ngOnInit(){
     console.log('The Array I got is ', this.arrayToGet); //Undefined, Tried even with setTimeout
  }

  //A bunch of methods to work with the array I get
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'parent-component',
   template: '<div>
                <child-component [arrayToGet]="models"></child-component>
              </div>',
   //A bunch of Styles and Providers
})

export class ParentComponent{
   models;

   constructor(......){}

   ngOnInit(){
      //Get an array from a service assign to this.models;
   }
}
```

The problem is that I can't perform any operations on `arrayToGet` inside my `ChildComponent`. However I am able to use the properties on `arrayToGet` inside my `ChildComponent`'s HTML.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your parent component never initializes models. So it's undefined. All your code contains is a comment. A comment doesn't do anything. If you want us to explain why your actual code behaves the way it does, post your actual code. My guess is that you don't understand the principle of asynchronism. But it's only a guess.

Comment: Actual code is very huge. So I thought of abstracting to make it less cumbersome. The code that I posted gives an idea of what happens.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You don't need to post all your huge real code. Only a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem. The code you posted reproduces the problem, but I doubt the problem is the same in your real code, because the real code probably initializes models somehow.

Comment: See demo app here http://www.freakyjolly.com/example-app-share-data-between-angular-components-using-input-decorator/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever trying to pass data from `parent` to `child` using `@Input` decorator and passing data is not available at the time of `child` initialzation, better to use `setter`, instead of just binding directly in to variable in `child` component. Using `setter` will updates the child component vairable, whenever the data is updated in parent component.

```
export Class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
  arrayToGet; //An array that I want to pass from Parent to child

  ngOnInit(){
     console.log('The Array I got is ', this.arrayToGet); //Undefined, Tried even with setTimeout
  }

  @Input('arrayToGet')
  set _arrayToGet(data: Array) {
     this.arrayToGet = data;
     console.log(this.arrayToGet);
  }

  //A bunch of methods to work with the array I get
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-component [arrayToGet]="models"></child-component>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent {
  private models: Array<any> = ["hello", "world"];
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() arrayToGet;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('arrayToGet', this.arrayToGet);
    }
}
```