# Access to the parent value from child component [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript

AppComponent (parent) has main page (layout) and counter of pages:

```
export class AppComponent {
  counter = '1/3';
}

<div class="counter">
  {{counter}}
</div>
```

There are also two components (children) that are responsible for the content of pages. From child components, need to have access to the parent value (counter).

One of them:

```
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';

export class Page1Component {
  app: AppComponent;
}
SomeEvent($event) {
  this.app.counter='2/3';
}

<div class="content">
 ...
</div>
```

After the event I get an error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined"

Question:
How to manipulate a parent variable correctly?

Comment: Refer this link to access the parent value from child component : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138267/accessing-the-data-passed-using-input-decorator/46138385#46138385)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the parent variable to the child component through input property.

```
    import {Input} from '@angular/core';

    export class Page1Component {
      @Input() counter;

    SomeEvent($event) {
      this.counter='2/3';
    }
    }
```

and in your app you can pass the counter

> app.component.html

```
<page1 [counter]="counter"><page1>
```

and if you want to change the counter of parent as well you can define an output event emitter and call the method in parent when some event occurs

**Update** if you want to change the couter of parent, you can try this:

```
import {Output} from '@angular/core';

export class Page1Component {
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

SomeEvent($event) {
  this.change.emit();
}
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<page1 [change]="counterChanged()"><page1>
```

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent{
counterChanged() {
this.counter = "whatever value";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add input field in your child component:

```
@Input() counter: any;
```

And then you can bind to this porperty in parent html:

```
<child-component-selector [counter]="counter"></child-component-selector>
```

Comment: ChildComponent it's a content of page (AppComponent). In this cause the markup will break. I just want to change the counter when called one of child component.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing this the wrong way you can't do this like that..
You  have to do this in the following way by `@Input` tag

for example:

```
 export class AppComponent {
   counter = '1/3';
}
```

in  the html of app component
`<ChildComponent [counter]="counter"></ChildComponent>`

in your child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
export class ChildComponent{
        @Input() counter:any;

         //after this you can use counter
   }
```

more on this is [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: ChildComponent it's a content of page (AppComponent). In this cause the markup will break. I just want to change the counter when called one of child component.

Comment: you can change the selector.Right?Or am i mistaken?.Correct me if i am wrong